# Hugo Table of Contents have extra dot in front

Tags: css, go, hugo

I am using Hugo static site generator to create a website. I am using this code snippet, as given in docs to create TOC:

```
<div id="toc" class="well col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    {{ .TableOfContents }}
</div>
```

This is the generated code:

```
<div id="toc" class="well col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <nav id="TableOfContents">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#step-1-install-hugo:c57cc0038c788519b441e0331c8bebc7">Step 1. Install Hugo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-2-build-the-docs:c57cc0038c788519b441e0331c8bebc7">Step 2. Build the Docs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-3-change-the-docs-site:c57cc0038c788519b441e0331c8bebc7">Step 3. Change the docs site</a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-4-have-fun:c57cc0038c788519b441e0331c8bebc7">Step 4. Have fun</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Due to this I am getting a extra bullet. can anyone solve this? or can you suggest CSS to remove bullets just from the first `ul`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following css:

```
#toc ul { 
  list-style-type: none; 
}

#toc ul ul { 
  list-style-type: disc; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked well for my needs

```
{{ .TableOfContents | replaceRE "<ul>[[:space:]]*<li>[[:space:]]*<ul>" "<ul>" | replaceRE "</ul>[[:space:]]*</li>[[:space:]]*</ul>" "</ul>" |  safeHTML }}
```

along with this css

```
nav > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
```